# Epoch time field extraction in splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation

How can we write regex or field extraction for below logs? Field is start and end where value is in epoch format and i want to change this in human readable format ..

```
cs7=45.45 cs7Label=latitude cs8=28.05 cs8Label=longitude Customer=Romania-UPC start=1604484735041 request=scoala.bibliotecapemobil.ro/download.php ref=https://scoala.bibliotecapemobil.ro/893/borgia requestMethod=GET qstr=book_id\=893&user_id\=&download\=pdf cn1=200 app=HTTPS act=REQ_PASSED deviceExternalId=37982221230540227 sip=195.191.47.151 spt=443 in=45 xff=82.208.137.89 cpt=62542 src=82.208.137.89 ver=TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 end=1604484735097
```

Answer (score 0):

Field extraction at search time can be done with the `extract` command.

```
... | extract pairdelim=" " kvdelim="=" | ...
```

Convert the time field using `strptime()`.

```
... | eval start=strptime(start, "%s%3N")
```

Index-time field extraction should be automatic, but try these props.conf settings for both extraction and time processing.

```
[mysourcetype]
TIME_PREFIX = start=
TIME_FORMAT = %s%3N
MAX_TIMESTAMP_LOOKAHEAD = 13
SHOULD_LINEMERGE = false
LINE_BREAKER = ([\r\n]+)
KV_MODE = auto
```

Comment: thanks Rich .. but i wanted to change this to human readable format ..

Comment: No problem.  Use `strftime()` for that.  `... | eval startstr=strftime(strptime(start, "%s%3N"), "%c")`.

Comment: also can i get the time zone of  epoch time like CEST,GMT?

Comment: To get milliseconds, just change the format string.  See the Search Reference manual for how to write format strings.  `... | eval startstr=strftime(strptime(start, "%s%3N"), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N%Z")`

Comment: Splunk converts timestamps to UTC when they're ingested and converts them to the user's preferred time zone on display.

Comment: thanks a lot Rich for your quick help  ..its working perfectly ..